LWN-Simulator Installation From docker
I'm new and I have a problem installing Lora simulator from docker. I have followed all the steps in the installation.
https://github.com/UniCT-ARSLab/LWN-Simulator
In the second step, run the built container: docker-compose up. I got this error:
[+] Running 2/2

Network lwn-simulator_default Created

Container lorawan-simulator   Created

Attaching to lorawan-simulator

lorawan-simulator | exec ./entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory

lorawan-simulator exited with code 1

Entrypoint.sh file still in docker folder.
I tried to add new path (D:\LWN-Simulator\LWN-Simulator\docker) in edit system environment variables.

Please share your Dockerfile and/or docker-compose.yml.

this is dockerfile
https://github.com/UniCT-ARSLab/LWN-Simulator/blob/main/Dockerfile
and this is docker-compose.yml
https://github.com/UniCT-ARSLab/LWN-Simulator/blob/main/docker-compose.yml

This works fine for me.

The error you are getting suggests that you have not got the full repository or you are in the wrong directory. Did you follow the instructions to the letter? This is what I did:
git clone git@github.com:UniCT-ARSLab/LWN-Simulator.git
cd LWN-Simulator/
docker-compose build && docker-compose up

The last command can be split into two commands as specified in the project README.md.

Yes, I followed the instruction. I don't know why but instead of using git clone, I downloaded the zip because I guess some file was missed. Then I did docker-compose build && docker-compose and It worked. Anyway, thank you so much for your help.

Great. Happy to hear the problem is solved. Please be so kind as to accept my answer.
